# Same distance between several UILabels

Tags: xcode, interface-builder

In Xcode 5.0.2 when I select the 5 labels (by holding SHIFT key and clicking them) as shown at the below screenshot -

[image]

Is there an easy way in Xcode to put all labels at same distance from each other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make constraints between the bottom of each label and the top of the next label. Set the `constant` of each constraint to the same value.

You can select all the labels (except the last one) and do that in a single move using the second button in the widget at the bottom of the storyboard canvas.

[image]

This is the sort of thing you are trying to achieve:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this works well. Is there please a way to fix the yellow warnings for "mispaced views" (after adding constraints) - other than manually trying to move the views at the exact pixel?

Comment: Notice in the first screen shot that I've asked for "Update... all frames in container!" If you forget to do that, ask the third button in the widget to update the frames for you, at any time.